# Unable to extract link in href within <a> tag using Cheerio

Tags: web-scraping, extract, cheerio

I'm trying to extract the audiobook link in Amazon and i'm pretty sure I got the selector part right, but it can't find the element

```
function queryAudiobooklink($) {
    const audiobookElement = $('li.swatchElement.unselected span.a-list-item span.a-button.a-spacing-mini.a-button-toggle.format span.a-button-inner #a-autoid-3-announce');
    console.log(audiobookElement.html());
    if (audiobookElement.length > 0) {
        const href = audiobookElement.attr('href');
        if (href) {
            const aLink = 'https://www.amazon.com' + href;
            return aLink;
        }
    }
    return 'Audiobook element not found';
}
```

I copy pasted the selector from another scrapper(using puppeteer) and it works so I'm not sure what exactly is the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgxmx.png)

this is what the element looks like in the browser. Could the issue be my code?

Comment: Puppeteer works with the live site and runs JS in the browser. Cheerio doesn't if you're fetching the page's static HTML with a simple HTTP request. You have a screenshot of the dev tools, but you probably should be looking in `view-source:` to verify your element is there in the plain text HTTP response you probably have. Please add details or provide the actual site to get further assistance. Is this some Amazon page? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to help me out! I didn't know about view-source before and I'm looking at it now. It's an amazon page and I'm only trying to get the audiobook, kindle and paperback link. the URL is https://www.amazon.com/Gift-Fear-Gavin-Becker-ebook/dp/B0036Z9U2A/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1SW0Y1R0C4K0S&keywords=The+Gift+of+Fear&qid=1692783090&s=digital-text&sprefix=the+gift+of+fear%2Cdigital-text%2C336&sr=1-1

Comment: Also, I think i've been able to make it work now. I just inspected view source. However, when I try to run it a couple of times, it ends up not finding the audiobook link element, without changing the code that previously worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response--can you [edit] to share your current code?